# Coloring Cells via VBA for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

My question is now answered. I have selected several cells in excel, e.g. Range("B3:F6"). Running the following code, that I copied from the answer below results in coloring the empty cells grey:

```
Sub CellColor()
    
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

(I have already deleted my false code accidentally.)

Comment: `Set rrange = Selection.Cells` as you are dealing with objects. (although the variable is fairly pointless here)

Comment: You're not declaring your range variable nor setting it. For a range you need: `Dim rrange As Range: Set rrange = Selection.Cells`. Also declare `Dim c As Range`, use Option Explicit to prevent forgetting that.

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It still doesn't do what I want it to unfortunately. Conditional formatting didn't work either.

Comment: C is a range so just `c.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Highlight Empty Cells in Range

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub CellColor()
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

```vb
Sub HighlightEmpties()
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "No range selected.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then
                Set urg = cell
            Else
                Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
   
    If urg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No empty cells found.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    urg.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    
End Sub
```